# Getting data from Qfield back into QGIS

Tags: qgis, qfield

This should be an easy task but I have struggled for 2 days trying to do it. I have a Qfield project with a single point layer (set to offline edit). I have a simple basemap (OpenstreetMap). I collect data points on the handheld and all looks good. I copy the whole folder containing the project back in to the import folder for QGis sych. When I import the project the points are missing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure the points layer source data is stored in the same file as the project?

Comment: I used the plugin QFielddsync to package the project. This saved it to a location on my C drive under a folder named export. I then copied this file over to the handheld. To get it back again off the handheld I copy the updated file to the import folder and then press Synchronize from Field option on QField sync. Not sure how else to do this.

Comment: Oh, I see. It sounds like QFieldsync should be handling all the file transfers. If it's not, then you might need to make a bug report. I would double-check that the source data file paths are correct before and after synchronizing.

Comment: When I transferred the files from mobile, the data file names all changed. Have you checked they use the same file name. I am new to this but when I checked the sync it is still require manual works that means you need to check all file names to make sure the y match.

Comment: I have the Same Problem. How ist checking for the Same File Name meant? When sync converts the Data for qfield it sets the Name the Same way aß in the Project. when i try to sync back to the Project i chose the folder i Put them in. In my case import. Then i Press synchronize. It seems to do something, but the new points from the offline layer of qfield dont appear in the Project. Trying again results in an Error because data have already been synchronized....
The new points seem to be stored in data.gpkg. but i am Not able to add them to the original shp layer in the Project...

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate that you have posted this nearly 3 years ago but i had the same issue. The way i got my data over to QGIS is as follows:

1. In QField go to 'open local file' open 'QField files directory' then 'imported project'
2. Instead of clicking to go into the folder click on the three dots at the side, there should be the option to 'export to folder' choose where you want the exported data to be saved.
3. with your tablet plugged in copy and paste the exported data onto your computer.
4. in QGIS go to 'plugins' then 'Qfield sync' then 'syncroise from QField' locate your folder and finaly select 'syncronise'

hopefully this makes sense